# Swagger - NotSupportedException: Ambiguous HTTP method for action

Tags: swagger

**NotSupportedException: Ambiguous HTTP method for action - AAON.Insiite.Api.Controllers.TokenController.Get (AAON.Insiite.Api). Actions require an explicit HttpMethod binding for Swagger 2.0**

I've read the several questions regarding this issue on SO but none of the solutions have worked.

I've tried:

- Adding [HttpGet] to the method in question.
- Adding [NonAction] to the method in question.
- Changing access modifier of method to Protected.
- Deleting the method still throws an exception for the now deleted method.
- Cleared Visual Studio Cache

I've tried clearing my visual studio cache but to no avail.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok("Running");
    }
```

Comment: Which library/framework is this question about - Swashbuckle or Swagger-Net or something else?

Answer (score -11, accepted):

The issue was a controller naming convention. Solved.

Comment: can you post the full answer please, this leaves us guessing as to what you did

Comment: If you ever come back to this, it would be helpful to see what you changed.

Answer (score 2):

According to @Crumblenautjs answer, I had a similar problem with the custom routing convention. After debugging for a while I discovered that also **RouteAnalyzer_Main** (which is used by swagger to define routes) routes are being replaced together with "my" controllers.

My solution is to skip Apply when RouteAnalyzer occurs, at least works for my solution.

```
public void Apply(ControllerModel controller)
{
    if (controller.ControllerName == "RouteAnalyzer_Main")
    {
        return;
    }
}
```